# meTypeset installation and python module installation, converting word docs to XML

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

hope everyone doing good..today am come up with an  different question..i need to convert word docs to XML am using meTypeset..https://github.com/MartinPaulEve/meTypeset..because i need to validate high end journal docs..it needs python and java environment .i have installed both and i tried to run meTypeset.py and its say error message like  no modules named lxml (for your quicker reference pls refer image1)..hence tried to install module in python like ths "pip3 install lxml" its show like  "FILE "" syntax error (for your quicker reference pls refer image 2).

I have following questions now
 1. how to install metypeset properly 
 2. what are all prerequisite for installing metypeset..
 3.what version of python is required to use metypeset..
 4.suggestion for  converting docs to xml
 5.suggestions about JATS xml editor 
 6.suggestion about validation in xml conversions(high priority)

Thanks in advance

[image: image1]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

and i have found the solution for this ..we have to install lxml module for this through python web link